# ¿Cómo ingresar un delimitador cada vez que el usuario ingrese dos caracteres en un TextBox?

Tags: c#, regex

Estoy programando una aplicación donde el usuario tiene que ingresar un número en hexadecimal en un `TextBox` y quiero que por cada byte (cada dos caracteres) se ponga un "-".

Intenté con este código:

```
private void txtEPC_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtTMP = (TextBox)sender;
    if (Regex.IsMatch(txtTMP.Text, "[A-F0-9]{2}$"))
    {
        txtEPC.Text = Regex.Replace(txtTMP.Text, "[A-F0-9]{2}$", "$0-");
        txtEPC.SelectionStart = txtEPC.Text.Length;
    }
}
```

Pero no me funcionó, no me dejaba usar el *backspace*, porque volvía a ingresarse el guión cada vez que se cumplía la expresión regular.

He visto en algunas páginas web, que tiene un `TextBox` y se ve el delimitador opaco y si escribes o borras caracteres ese delimitador no se afecta en nada, los caracteres se escriben en sus lados, no por encima.

Quería hacer algo así, pero la verdad no tengo idea de cómo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Regex

Una forma sencilla de resolver el problema que estás teniendo, es reemplazar únicamente cuando hay 2 caracteres hexadecimales, **seguidos por otro** caracter hexadecimal.

```
[A-F0-9]{2}(?=[A-F0-9])
```

- Estamos utilizando `(?=`...`)`, que es una [inspección positiva](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.100).aspx#mt137) ([*positive lookahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)). Una inspección intentará realizar la aserción (que esté seguido por `[A-F0-9]`), pero no va a consumir caracteres (volverá a donde estaba antes de intentarlo).

Código:

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

```cs
string patron = @"[A-F0-9]{2}(?=[A-F0-9])";
string reempl = @"$0-";
Regex regex   = new Regex(patron, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

// ...

string resultado = regex.Replace(texto, reempl);
```

Esto te evitaría el problema al eliminar un guión al final del texto, pero no un guión intermedio. Para eso, deberías verificar qué caracter se está ingresando, o evaluar la posición actual del cursor (dónde se está escribiendo).

---

#### MaskedTextBox

No obstante, para este caso, quizás te sea más sencillo realizarlo con un [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx), que es el tipo de control que estás describiendo en la pregunta. Por ejemplo, para 4 bytes, podrías usar la máscara:

```
maskedTextBox1.Mask = "AA-AA-AA-AA";
```

- Controla alfanuméricos, faltaría reducir los caracteres aceptados

Para un número variable de bytes, habría que modificar la máscara según cambia el texto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudó bastante. Ambas son buenas propuestas, pero creo que me quedaré con el `maskedTextBox`, es más sencillo. :D